# How do I update the keycloak client?

Tags: keycloak

I have a `12.0.1` instance and I would like to upgrade to `12.0.2`. I followed the guide here https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/ however I do not seem to have the new option that was added here (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/91a51c2dbeb770e0202e89b438fc16963a5eed21) in my UI. If I go to Server Info in the admin panel it shows  `12.0.2` as the version.

What am I missing? Do I need to update the client separately? I downloaded the latest archive and copied the files from my old `KEYCLOAK_HOME/standalone/` into the new folder and restarted keycloak. The DB was migrated from what I can tell but that UI options is just missing.

Do I need to do something to my existing realm to activate this feature?

Comment: What is "client" in your meaning? Where exactly in the UI are you expecting to see mentioned update?

Comment: By client I mean the web UI which I think is actually part of the server. The feature I am missing is under federated LDAP, in Mappers under "user-attribute-ldap-mapper". Right under "Is Mandatory In LDAP" there should be a field for default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak release `12.0.2` doesn't contain linked KEYCLOAK-16606 change. See the history of the commits: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/12.0.2/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/mappers/UserAttributeLDAPStorageMapper.java You need to build your own custom Keycloak release from the master or wait until change will be released.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow looked at that wrong on github and thought it was in this release.